# Why does replacing multiple columns change the dtype

Tags: pandas

Why does replacing one value give `object` dtype but replacing two values give `float64` dtype?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
In [6]: df.replace({1: None})
Out[6]: 
      a  b
0  None  4
1     2  5
2     3  6

In [7]: df.replace({1: None, 5: None})
Out[7]: 
     a    b
0  NaN  4.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  6.0

In [8]: df.replace({1: None}).dtypes
Out[8]: 
a    object
b    object
dtype: object

In [9]: df.replace({1: None, 5: None}).dtypes
Out[9]: 
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Just the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
df.replace({1: None})
df.replace({1: None, 5: None})
df.replace({1: None}).dtypes
df.replace({1: None, 5: None}).dtypes
```

Comment: I found [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) in documentation.

Comment: That's interesting information but I don't think it clarifies in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be buried in the `replace` `if`/`then` logic that does something slightly different depending on the length of the `mapping`

I you want consistent behavior, don't use `None`.  Use `np.nan`

```
df.replace({1: np.nan})

     a    b
0  NaN  4.0
1  2.0  5.0
2  3.0  6.0
```

Or

```
df.replace({1: np.nan, 5: np.nan})

     a    b
0  NaN  4.0
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  6.0
```

---

If you want to replace one column and leave the others alone, pass a nested dictionary that specifies what to do for which column

```
df.replace({'a': {1: np.nan}})

     a  b
0  NaN  4
1  2.0  5
2  3.0  6
```

Or

```
df.replace({'a': {1: np.nan}, 'b': {5: None}})

     a     b
0  NaN     4
1  2.0  None
2  3.0     6
```